# I get Promise { <pending> } as returned value and also calling in async scope gives me undefined immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Im trying to return a value from a Promise in async-await form and use it in another function in another file, but I do have problem because my Promise doesnt return any value.
When im trying to console.log('website') it returns me undefined immediately (it's like the value is not being fetched at all from API services). I dont know what im doing wrong, I really love to learn about Promises and Async-Await but each time im trying to work with them im getting more confused.

```
const dns = require('dns')
const iplocation = require("iplocation").default;
const emojiFlags = require('emoji-flags');

const getServerIPAddress = async (server) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.lookup(server, (err, address) => {
            if (err) throw reject(err);
            resolve(address);
        });
    });
};


const getServerLocation = async (server) => {
    const ip = await getServerIPAddress(server)

    iplocation(ip).then((res) => {
        const country = emojiFlags.countryCode(res.countryCode)
        const result = `Location: ${country.emoji} ${country.name}`
        return result
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return `Location: Unknown`
    });
}

(async function() {
    console.log(await getServerLocation('www.google.com'))
})()


module.exports = {
    getServerLocation
}
```

It is really important for me to get result from this function first, then use its value in another function. I wish you could give me tips on how to do tasks asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly using `async` so it's not apparent why you're using `then` as well. If you use `then` then you *must* return the promise as well in order to preserve the promise chain:

```
const getServerLocation = async (server) => {
    const ip = await getServerIPAddress(server)

    return iplocation(ip).then((res) => {
        const country = emojiFlags.countryCode(res.countryCode)
        const result = `Location: ${country.emoji} ${country.name}`
        return result
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return `Location: Unknown`
    });
}
```

Otherwise just async this:

```
const getServerLocation = async (server) => {
    const ip = await getServerIPAddress(server)

    let res = await iplocation(ip);

    const country = emojiFlags.countryCode(res.countryCode)
    const result = `Location: ${country.emoji} ${country.name}`
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const getServerLocation = async (server) => {
    const ip = await getServerIPAddress(server)

   //you need to return
    return iplocation(ip).then((res) => {
        const country = emojiFlags.countryCode(res.countryCode)
        const result = `Location: ${country.emoji} ${country.name}`
        return result
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return `Location: Unknown`
    });
}
```